# Regarding Structs and Using Them With Array's

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm trying to write a program that will take every line from a text file and load the value into an array. For some reason however, when I try create a dynamic array and try to put information in any position beyond 0, the information from from position zero gets copied over and I can't seem to understand why. Specifically in this program its in the readInventory function I have written. Basically, why can't I copy one struct to the other?

Sample from file

```
A009 Strawberries_Case 0 12.50 8
4028 STRAWBERRIES_PINT 0 0.99 104
4383 MINNEOLAS 1 0.79 187.3
4261 Rice_1_LB_Bag 0 0.49 107
```

Code from program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Product
{
   string PLU;
   string name;
   int salesType;
   double unitPrice/*rice per pound*/;
   double inventory;
};

struct ItemSold
{
   string PLU;
   string name;
   double cost;

};

Product *inventoryLevels = new Product[100];
ItemSold *itemsSold = new ItemSold[100];

bool readInventory(string filename, int &numberOfItems);
double checkout(int inventoryLength);
double price(string PLU, double units);
int typeCheck(string PLU, int inventoryLength);
string nameCheck(string PLU, int inventoryLength);



int main()
{

   int numberOfItems = 0;
   string filename = "products.txt";
   int total;

   if (readInventory(filename, numberOfItems))
   {
      cout << "Inventory file has errors, please make changes before continuing" << endl << endl;
   }


   total = checkout(numberOfItems);
   cout << total;


   system("pause");
}



double checkout(int inventoryLength)
{  // Function that will be used to perform the checkout by the user


   string PLU = "1";

   double units/*pounds*/;
   int salesType;
   int counter = 0;
   int temp;
   double total = 0;

   while (PLU != "0")
   {
      cout << "Enter a PLU: ";
      cin >> PLU;
      itemsSold[counter].PLU = PLU;

      if (PLU == "0")
      {
         // do nothing
      }

      else
      {
         itemsSold[counter].name = nameCheck(PLU, inventoryLength);
         if (typeCheck(PLU, inventoryLength) == 0)
         {
            cout << " Enter the number of units being bought: ";
            cin >> units;
            while (units > inventoryLevels[counter].inventory)
            {
               cout << "You have entered in more units than we have on hand \n Please reduce the number of units being bought\n";
               cout << " Enter the number of units being bought: ";
               cin >> units;
            }

            itemsSold[counter].cost = price(PLU, units);
            inventoryLevels[counter].inventory -= units;


         }
         else
         {
            cout << "Enter the number of pounds of the item being bought: ";
            cin >> units;
            itemsSold[counter].cost = price(PLU, units);

            while (units > inventoryLevels[counter].inventory)
            {
               cout << "You have entered in more pounds than we have on hand \n Please reduce the number of pounds being bought\n";
               cout << "Enter the number of pounds of the item being bought: ";
               cin >> units;
            }

            inventoryLevels[counter].inventory -= units;

         }

         counter++;
      }


   }

   temp = counter;
   while (temp >= 0)
   {
      total += itemsSold[temp].cost;
      temp--;
   }



   return total;

}


string nameCheck(string PLU, int inventoryLength)
{
   for (int k = 0; k < inventoryLength; k++)
   {
      if (inventoryLevels[k].PLU == PLU)
      {
         return inventoryLevels[k].name;
      }
   }

   return "We are currently out of stock of this item.";
}

int typeCheck(string PLU, int inventoryLength)
{
   for (int k = 0; k < inventoryLength ; k++)
   {
      if (inventoryLevels[k].PLU == PLU)
      {
         return inventoryLevels[k].salesType;
      }
   }
}


double price(string PLU, double units)
{ // 
   double price;

   for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++)
   {
      if (inventoryLevels[k].PLU == PLU)
      {
        price = units * (inventoryLevels[k].unitPrice);
        return price;
      }
   }

}


bool readInventory(string filename, int &numberOfItems)
{
   // File object
   fstream inventory;

   // Some temp variable used to validate information is still in file while it is being transfered to array
   //string temp;

   // Open the inventory file
   inventory.open(filename);



   // Will temporarily hold the properties of an item until loaded onto the array
   Product temp;


   // Counter will allow for a new item to be stored onto the next available location in the array
   int counter = 0;


   // Will demonstrate whether or not there is an error
   int error = 0;

   // Store items and their properties in the global array
   while (inventory >> temp.PLU >> temp.name >> temp.salesType >> temp.unitPrice >> temp.inventory)
   {
      // Checks to see if they 


      if ((temp.PLU.at(0) > 57) || (temp.PLU.at(1) > 57) || (temp.PLU.at(2) > 57) || (temp.PLU.at(3) > 57))
      {
         error++;
      }

      else
      { 

         inventoryLevels[numberOfItems].PLU = temp.PLU;
         inventoryLevels[numberOfItems].name = temp.name;
         inventoryLevels[numberOfItems].salesType = temp.salesType;
         inventoryLevels[numberOfItems].unitPrice = temp.unitPrice;
         inventoryLevels[numberOfItems].inventory = temp.inventory;

       numberOfItems++;
      counter++;
      }


   }

   // If there is no error return true
   if (error == 0)
   {
      return false;
   }
   // If there is an error return false
   else if (error > 0)
   {
      return true;
   }

}
```

Comment: FWIW `typeCheck` and `price` are missing return statements.

Comment: I understand that, but  I'm having issues prior to even getting to running those statements. What I mean is, when you look at readInventory and see how I'm loading values from a temp structure into the global array. the temp structure reads in every line from the file, but it does not get loaded into the array.

Comment: Clearly you have some issues with reading that file. Why don't you take an advantage of you debugger and put some breakpoints there to see what you are actually reading to your temp structure?

Comment: Yeah thats how I figured out the problem in the first place. I should be more clear I suppose. If you take a look at the else statement in the readInventory function thats where I'm confused as to why it doesn't work. The values inside temp change however when I try to assign them to the array of inventoryLevels nothing happens. Reading isn't the problem.

Comment: Why not use a vector instead of hardcoding an arbitrary number of objects?

Comment: Wanted to do that but arrays must be used for the assignment

Comment: You should not write this much code without testing any of it. Start small and simple, then build up, testing at every step and developing new functions in isolation. That way when you hit a snag, it's easy to find. In this case, once I correct the syntax errors and make up some fake data, the code runs without error.

Comment: So there are just some syntax error I need to fix and it should be ok? My main concern is I dont know why my temp struct wont transfer to my array

Comment: An incredibly useful technique: when you can see the error and reproduce it (i.e. get the error over and over), simplify the code as much as you can, testing at every step. Take out all of the functions you're not using. Remove the struct fields one by one. Don't read the data file, just hard-code a couple of sets of values. If at any point the error vanishes, take a close look at the last thing you removed. Chances are you'll discover the bug along the way, but otherwise you'll wind up with a [minimal complete solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you can show us.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign values here,

```
while (inventory >> temp.PLU >> temp.name >> temp.salesType >> temp.unitPrice >> temp.inventory)
```

Am I right to assume that the input file is in the format (since you're assigning each line to the variables?

> line 1: Some string you want assigned to  PLU
>   line 2: Some string you want assigned to name
>   line 3: Some Int you want assigned to salestype 
>   ..........
>   ..........
>   line n:string PLU

Comment: Edited the original post to demonstrate this


So in each part of the struct is differentiated by a space

The program reads into the temp just fine, its just when i try to assign temp to inventoryLevels[1] it doesnt copy.And so on and so forth. The counter moves just fine, but every subsequent position from the first one in the array just gets assigned what the first line of code that I want to be assigned

Comment: Ok yes, it seems like the problem is in the "assignment" part. At first I suspected perhaps the index counter or the reading input is giving you problems. Doesn't seem like it.

Comment: Yeah thats what I dont understand. The indexing is fine, however when trying to assign it doesn't do what I require. Im assuming the fix is simple I just don't know what it is.

Comment: Just to confirm, when you tried printing out the values of the temp(struct), you get the desired output ? However, after assigning the temp struct to the array what happens is `inventoryLevels[2] =  inventoryLevels[1] =  inventoryLevels[0]` ?